# Is char buf[] = "test" equivalent to String buf = new String("test")?

Tags: java, c

Is

```
char buf[] = "test";
```

in C equivalent to

```
String buf = new String("test");
```

in Java?

And is

```
char *buf;
buf = "test";
```

equivalent to

```
String buf = "test";
```

?

Comment: In general, you can replace C strings with a Java `String`. In some cases, you want to use `char[]` in both. Note that Java `char` is 16-bit and unsigned to accommodate the full range of UTF-16 code points, while C `char` only needs to accommodate the `ASCII` character set (C99 states at least 8-bit) and can be either `signed` or `unsigned` depending on implementation.

Comment: Since a String in Java is immutable it would be closer to a `const char*` in C.

Comment: I know character array is not object.

Comment: Actually, it is.  Arrays are objects too.

Comment: I am comparing initialization and assignment methods in C and Java. My question in not about unicode something like that.

Answer (score 9):

It's difficult to say they're *equivalent*, although I understand what you're driving at.

Your C version is a sequence of 8-bit chars. The Java variant is Unicode-aware.

Secondly, in Java you're creating an object with behaviour, rather than just a sequence of chars.

Finally, the Java variant is *immutable*. You can change the reference, but not the underlying set of characters (this is a function of being wrapped by the `String` object)

For something largely equivalent you could use an array of bytes in Java. Note that this wouldn't be null-terminated, however. Java arrays are aware of their length rather than using a convention of null-termination. Alternatively a closer C++ equivalent would probaly be `std::string`

Comment: +1 But to be pedantic, it's not necessarily 8-bit chars. The number of bits in each char is equal to `CHAR_BIT` (defined in `limits.h`)

Answer (score 1):

The first two are not equivalent. In Java, the String object, besides storing a char array, contains also other things (e.g. the length field). The java version is, of course, more OO.

The second ones are equivalent with the same observations as above. They are both pointers to containers of characters. The c container is a simple char array, while the string is a full-fledged object.

Answer (score 1):

This question can't really be answered - you're comparing apples to oranges.

In C, a "string" is really just a `char` array, that is null-terminated (that is, a `'\0'` byte at the end, placed by the compiler, and expected by the `str__()` library functions.

In Java, `String` is an object, that holds (possibly among other things), an array of characters, and an integer count.

They are different things, and they are used differently.  Is there something specific you are trying to accomplish and having trouble with? If so, ask *that*, and we will try to answer it. Otherwise, this isn't really a valid question, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

No. These are different data types. `char buf[]` is an array and `String buf` is an object. The `String buf` will be dynamically sized and have plenty of helpful methods with it. `char buf[]` is a static sized chunk of memory holding 5 8-bit characters.

Comment: In C "test" is 5 bytes as its nul byte terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Below will create an array of characters

```
char buf[] = "test";
```

Where as `String buf = new String("test");` will lead to creation of a `String Object`, but internally its `char[]` itself which is made immutable internally using a String object wrapper. So its a representation difference in the above 2 programming languages.